# How to prevent that text in Tabs of TabPane (JavaFX) gets cut off?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to make a simple TabPane with tabs with `font-size = 20` in javafx.
When I let the `font-size` on default, everything is fine:
[image: 1]

When I change the `font-size` to `20`, the underside of letters like p gets cut off:
[image: 2]

I think that's the case, because a container around it is too small, but I tried changing different components of the TabPane in css (from the [substructure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tabpane) of TabPane) but can't get it too work. As you see in the screenshots, I tried to exaggerate the size of the buttons and everything around, so it wouldn't influence the label inside.

Here is the css code I ended with after removing stuff that didn't change anything anyway.

```css
TabPane .headers-region {
    -fx-pref-height: 100;
}


TabPane .tab {
    -fx-pref-height: 100;
    -fx-pref-width: 500;
}

TabPane .tab .tab-label {
    -fx-pref-height: 80;
    -fx-pref-width: 400;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-font-size: 20;
}
```

**EDIT**

Minimum reproducible example (like kleopatra suggested):

Java file:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Board");
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Claims and assumptions");
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("Path to the css file");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

CSS file:

```css
TabPane .tab-label {
    -fx-font-size: 20;
}
```

Comment: don't hard-code sizing constraints

Comment: Ikr, just did it now to make everything very big to find where te problem was.

Comment: but the hard-coding is nearly always part of the problem - never-ever do it :) Instead, use a really big font and see what happens (and post a [mcve] showing the effect)

Comment: Okay, I'll make one real quick.

Comment: the problem is the tabPane's tabMaxHeight: it's a stylableProperty set in modena to 22 (as is the tabMinHeight, making it effectively not resizable) - TabHeaderSkin respects those boundaries and clips the label. Configure the property to Double.MAX_NUMBER in code, or something really huge (don't know if/how to set the equivalent to double.max in the rule ;) in css, like `.tab-pane {-fx-tab-max-height: 100000;}`

Comment: btw: ScenicView is a nice tool to find the reason for layout quirks - the cause did show when inspecting the min/pref values of the headerSkin where the latter is smaller than the former :)

Comment: Wow ye that worked, I will try ScenicView for sure, many thanks :)

Comment: If you post it as an answer I will mark it as the answer :)